# Regex IfThenElse pattern returning null character

Tags: r, regex, conditional-statements

Using the pattern:

```
(?((?<=(Textbook|Online Class): (Yes|No))(?!(Textbook|Online Class): (Yes|No))).+|(?<=(\\d{4}))(?!(\U000)).+)
```

Gives me:

```
Error: null character not allowed
```

I wanted the pattern to discern if Textbook/Online: Yes/No is present and not followed by Textbook/Online: Yes/No then capture the rest, else find a four digit number not followed by `"\U000"` and capture the rest.

To be more specific, when the pattern is applied to strings

```
"ECP3203\U0001f60eawesomeJan 5th, 2005Some interesting stuff in the class.  Do the work and go to class and pay attention and its easy.  The paper is easier than it seems.00"
```

and

```
"ECP3203\U0001f60eawesomeDec 21st, 2010Textbook: NoEasy A.  Go to class and write down whatever she writes on the board and you will ace the tests.  Grading scheme also makes it easy to get an A.  I'd recommend taking this course.  The only problem is that she sometimes let's class discussions go off topic.00"
```

It should return

```
"Some interesting stuff in the class. Do the work and go to class and pay attention and its easy. The paper is easier than it seems.00"
```

and

```
"Easy A. Go to class and write down whatever she writes on the board and you will be the tests. Grading scheme also makes it easy to get an A. I'd recommend taking this course. The only problem is that she sometimes let's class discussions go off topic.00"
```

Comment: Please provide the complete  code that would let anyone else reproduce what you have by copying and pasting into R.

Comment: Try `sub("^.*?\\b\\d{4}(?:(?:Textbook|Online Class):\\s*(?:Yes|No))?", "", x, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Please view edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the following regex -

```
sub('.*\\d{4}(Textbook: (Yes|No))?', '', x)

#[1] "Some interesting stuff in the class.  Do the work and go to class and pay attention and its easy.  The paper is easier than it seems.00"                                                                                                                            

#[2] "Easy A.  Go to class and write down whatever she writes on the board and you will ace the tests.  Grading scheme also makes it easy to get an A.  I'd recommend taking this course.  The only problem is that she sometimes let's class discussions go off topic.00"
```

***data**

```
x <- c("ECP3203\U0001f60eawesomeJan 5th, 2005Some interesting stuff in the class.  Do the work and go to class and pay attention and its easy.  The paper is easier than it seems.00", 
       "ECP3203\U0001f60eawesomeDec 21st, 2010Textbook: NoEasy A.  Go to class and write down whatever she writes on the board and you will ace the tests.  Grading scheme also makes it easy to get an A.  I'd recommend taking this course.  The only problem is that she sometimes let's class discussions go off topic.00")
```